# What does Mongodb's compact actually do?

Tags: mongodb, padding, compact-database

Well, probably this should be clear from the documentation, sadly, this is not the case. My guess was, that compact make some kind of defragmentation of the colection - such that collection's paddingfactor would go bellow given value. However, this does not seem to be true:

```
> db.aaa.stats().paddingFactor
1.9980000000000002
> db.runCommand ( { compact: 'aaa', paddingFactor: 1.1 } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.aaa.stats().paddingFactor
1.9980000000000002
> db.runCommand ( { compact: 'aaa', paddingFactor: 3 } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.aaa.stats().paddingFactor
1.9980000000000002
```

If this is not the way to change the padding factor of a collection, is there some other way to do so?

Comment: Hm, `compact` should remove the padding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *My guess was, that compact make some kind of DE-fragmentation of the collection*

Yes. It rewrites, DE-fragments all the data and the indexes on the collection.

> *such that collection's paddingfactor*

No. It does not change the padding factor of the collection.

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/):

> compact compacts existing documents but does not reset paddingFactor
>   statistics for the collection. After the compact MongoDB will use the
>   existing paddingFactor when allocating new records for documents in
>   this collection.

So when you execute the below command,

```
db.runCommand ( { compact: 'aaa', paddingFactor: 1.1 } )
```

the record size of the existing documents in the collection get altered using the specified padding factor. That is, all the **existing** records will now have `10%` of their `document size` as their `padding` size.

So after the DE-fragmentation all the existing records will have their sizes altered as,

```
record size = document size + (10% of document size)
```

And it **does not** the affect or change padding factor for the entire collection.

> *way to change the padding factor of a collection, is there some other way to do so?*

No. You can't select nor change the padding factor for a collection. From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/):

> padding factor:
>       An automatically-calibrated constant used to determine how much extra space MongoDB should allocate per document container on disk. A
>   padding factor of 1 means that MongoDB will allocate only the amount
>   of space needed for the document. A padding factor of 2 means that
>   MongoDB will allocate twice the amount of space required by the
>   document.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things out. It seems I was reading the docs in quite bad mindset.